# mapping a matrix to list....its tricky

Tags: list, dictionary, matrix

I have a list of 28 elements and a string of length 7 made up of 0,1,2,3 such as 0012031.
Now I want to read this string and depending on what character I read at a position I want to call a particular element from the list.

Think of the list's elements indexed as:

```
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   
00  ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '10', '11', '12',
10   '13', '14', '15', '16', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25',
20   '26', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36']
```

If the string has `0` at position 0, then I want `l[0]` (`00`). if the string has `3` at position 6, then I want `l[27]` (`36`).

Example:

```
String : '0012031'
character       position    call element from list
0               0           l[0]  - 00
0               1           l[1]  - 01
1               2           l[9]  - 12     
2               3           l[17] - 23
0               4           l[4]  - 04
3               5           l[26] - 35
1               6           l[13] - 16
```

Note: I'm working with a list, not a matrix.

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work.

Comment: What programming language is this even in?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a way to find the index given the character and position, the following formula should cover it:

```
listIndex = 7*character + position
```